# Constructor that takes nulltpr_t: function definition does not declare parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, nullptr

I have the following code:

```
class C {
private:
    void *data;

public:
    constexpr C(nullptr_t) : data(nullptr) { }
    C(int i) : data(new int(i)) { }
};
```

I have created a constructor which takes `nullptr_t`, so that I can have code similar to the following:

```
C foo(2);
// ...
foo = nullptr;
```

Code similar to this has worked previously on MSVC, however this code fails to compile on GCC 5.3.1 (using `-std=c++14`) with on the closing bracket of `C(nullptr_t)` with `error: function definition does not declare parameters`. Even if i give the parameter a name (in this case `_`), I get `error: expected ')' before '_'`. This also fails if the `constexpr` keyword is removed.

Why am I unable to declare such a constructor, and what are any possible workarounds?

Comment: You should `#include <cstddef>` at least. (And add `std::`.)

Comment: @songyuanyao thank you, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be a fan of "using namespace std", and you [just got tripped up by it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice):

```
constexpr C(std::nullptr_t) : data(nullptr) { }
```

gcc 5.3.1 compiles this, at `--std=c++14` conformance level:

```
[mrsam@octopus tmp]$ cat t.C
#include <iostream>

class C {
private:
    void *data;

public:
    constexpr C(std::nullptr_t) : data(nullptr) { }
    C(int i) : data(new int(i)) { }
};
[mrsam@octopus tmp]$ g++ -g -c --std=c++14 -o t.o t.C
[mrsam@octopus tmp]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it still failed with the same error. Are you specifying any additional flags to g++? cpp.sh also shows it: http://cpp.sh/7ldzs

Comment: No, no extra parameters. I updated my answer to document that.

Comment: Ah, i see it now, I didn't include anything, so `<cstddef>` was not included.